# Plotting antenna pattern in MATLAB

Tags: beamforming

I have a beamformed output, say

```
y = weights * signal,
```

where the signal is gaussian,i.e `signal = randn( 1 , 1e5 )`.

Now I want to visualise the output in angular domain, i.e I want to plot the gain of the resulting signal y as a function of elevation angles. I am considering the mainlobe of 'signal' to be pointing in (0 azimuth,0elevation). The weights are combination of amplitude weights and phase weights(exp(phase terms)). I am computing the antenna pattern in the following way:

```
pattern = abs(arrayFactor.* y).^2;
```

Is it correct to plot the antenna pattern of such a signal y by multiplying it by the array factor and then plotting its squared magnitude?(in case of isotopic element pattern.)

I would highly appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the array manifold (what you call array pattern) by a $N \times 1$ vector ${\bf{a}}\left ( \theta \right )$ where $\theta$ is the DOA and $N$ is the number of array elements. Further denote by the $N \times 1$ vector $\bf{x}_k$ the $k$-th snapshot of the array, then you are measuring the following signal:

\begin{equation}
{\bf{x}_k}= {\bf{a}}\left ( \theta \right ) s_k + {\bf{n}}_k
\end{equation}

where $s_k$ is the signal reflecting from the target and $n$ is a random noise.

Denote the beamformer by a $N \times 1 $ vector of weights ${\bf{w}}$, then the array response after beamforming would be

\begin{equation}
r(\theta) = {\bf{w}}^H {\bf{x_k}},
\end{equation}

Note that $r$ is a scalar for a given DOA $\theta$ and $\bf{w}$ is a function of $\theta$. Now, to get the array response for a variety of DOAs just change $\theta$.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I have right now. I have this term say r(theta) (r(0) in my case) and I have to draw its polar plot. Any ideas on how to draw this polar plot would be appreciated!

Comment: $r(0)$ is a scalar so either you change the beamformer for all $\theta$'s or you change the array manifold, either way once you have $r(-\pi:\Delta \theta:\pi)$ you plot it using matlab polar (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polar.html)